# ViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild() is not Working in Android

Tags: android, layout, viewflipper

I have my ViewFlipper layout like this,

```
   <ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <include android:id="@+id/mainView"  layout="@layout/activity_main" />
     <include android:id="@+id/readingView"  layout="@layout/get_reading" />
     <include android:id="@+id/datePickView" layout="@layout/custom_dialog" />
    </ViewFlipper>
```

and in the MainActivity,

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  final Context context = this;
  public ViewFlipper flipper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
  //Inflate the Views      
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button AddWaterReading=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);    //click on + button.
    AddWaterReading.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            flipper.setDisplayedChild(R.id.readingView);
            TextView txtgetCurrentDate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            txtgetCurrentDate.setText((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+c.get(Calendar.DATE)+"/"+c.get(Calendar.YEAR));                         
        }
    });
    }
```

when I click on the button "AddWaterReading, the Layout view is not changing to "readingView". I have used the ViewFlipper to change from Main layout to another Layout. But the Application error is shown up ("Unfortunately Application has stopped").

Logcat:

```
   03-01 07:29:58.122: E/Trace(3924): error opening trace file: No such file or   directory               (2)
   03-01 07:29:59.102: I/Choreographer(3924): Skipped 200 frames!  The application may   be doing too much work on its main thread.
   03-01 07:29:59.232: D/gralloc_goldfish(3924): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
   03-01 07:30:07.972: D/AndroidRuntime(3924): Shutting down VM
   03-01 07:30:07.972: W/dalvikvm(3924): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2bd39930)
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924): java.lang.NullPointerException
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):  at com.example.electricityreading.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
  03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  03-01 07:30:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(3924):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone please suggest how to switch between Layouts? I am new to Android.

Thanks.

Comment: There should be a stack trace in your log. Please add those details.

Answer (score 1):

ViewFlipper's `setDisplayedChild()` method takes the INDEX of the view to display, not the view: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setDisplayedChild(int)

Comment: Tried with this : flipper.setDisplayedChild(1); But it did not work.

Comment: Your `setContentView()` call in your `onCreate()` method is after you try to get flipper. That is why flipper is null. Move it before the flipper assignment.

Comment: It will at least get rid of the current null pointer exception you are having. If there is still an error it may have to do with the content of your three included layouts.

Comment: `vF.setDisplayedChild(INDEX);` works for me!
if you want to know what is the index of a child, you can write:
`vF.setDisplayedChild(vF.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.view)));`